# Displaying large amounts of text in CRM SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I'm trying to retrieve a CRM field that contains Base64-encoded image data and display it as an image within CRM. I found a blog by Jason Lattimer (https://jlattimer.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/ssrs-report-image-from-crm-note.html) that explains how he did this.

This seems to work within Visual Studio; however when I upload the report to CRM (Dynamics 365) I get an error.

I tried removing the image control and just showing the raw (base64-encoded) text and get the same error.

It seems like there is a 2000 character limit being imposed on fields retrieved from CRM. Has anyone else come across this problem and are there any known (supported) workarounds?

Comment: Is this your first time to upload or are you updating an existing report?

Comment: @GildonOpao it is a new, empty report with a single dataset. I think it is important to note that embedded images work fine, it is only when attempting to show an image loaded dynamically from CRM that I get this problem

Comment: I'd use the Entity Image for this purpose instead of a note

Comment: @Alex the issue with Entity Images is that the images are constrained in dimensions and size which don't meet my requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We couldn't work around this issue in SSRS. We've decided to try to replicate the report using a `Document Template`

Although Document Templates have their own problems (single dataset; limited query depth; etc.) these aren't affecting us in this use-case.